# How to check number of not handled requests- Nginx php

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We have an app server(php,nginx) that handles many request from our mobile apps. We are also using amazon load balancer(elb) for this instance. How can we see how many http requests don't really get handled by the nginx server(have no response).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ELB metrics in CloudWatch: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-metricscollected.html

I think the metric that might be the closest to what you're looking for is the `BackendConnectionErrors` metric.

The BackendConnectionErrors metric is the number of connections that were not successfully established between the load balancer and the registered instances.

There are also also these metrics:

```
HTTPCode_Backend_4XX, 
HTTPCode_Backend_5XX
```

Those metrics count the number of times those error response codes were returned by your backend instances. You must first establish a connection from the load balancer to the backends for those metrics to be emitted though.